# Visual Studio 2015 Adding Project to Local Git

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have a new project that I want to add to our repository on VSTS. When I click File -> Add Solution to Source Countrol in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, it creates a local Git repo locally by putting the Git folder inside my project folder.

How do I add this new project to our VSTS repository? Our repo on VSTS does NOT use Git either. It's the regular Team Foundation type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to your team project and create a work space from Team Explorer first. After this you can either [create a new project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs#create-a-new-app) or [add an exist project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs#add-an-existing-app).

Refer to this link for details: [Develop and share your code in TFVC using Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs#configure-your-workspace).